# URL not being passed to appdelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, appdelegate, ios-universal-links

I can't get dynamic links or universal links working. My app won't read in a URL. I've started with a fresh project, added a URL Scheme of com.company.AppLoginView and the below code into AppDelegate. I added a url in notes of: com.company.AppLoginView://Register?User=Name. Clicking the link requests to open the app which then opens. However, nothing seems to be passed to the app and the below isn't being called. What am I doing wrong? This is a completely empty app and should work.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if let scheme = url.scheme,
        scheme.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("com.myApp") == .orderedSame,
        let view = url.host {

        var parameters: [String: String] = [:]
        URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?.queryItems?.forEach {
            parameters[$0.name] = $0.value
        }

        print("View:\(view) Params:\(parameters) Scheme:\(scheme)")

//        redirect(to: view, with: parameters)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because target is iOS 13 and SceneDelegate takes over some functions from AppDelegate. In particular, open:url is replaced by SceneDelegate scene:openURLContexts.

More here: [Apple openURLContexts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene)

3 days of my life I won't get back!

Answer (score 2):

You should add ULR scheme and URL identifier to `plist`. You can use this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.company.AppLoginView</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.company.AppLoginView</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and check it with print in method in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print(url)
    return true
}
```

open Safari and type your address

> com.company.AppLoginView://Register?User=Name

Comment: this is working for me! some details here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application